# How to add a custom module to coded template in Hubspot?

Tags: html, jinja2, hubspot

I'm trying to add a custom module in a coded template in Hubspot, but cannot find any documentation or answers how to do that. Is that even possible?

**Custom module:** An example of a custom module can be any HTML component, I will add a simple text as example, module is called "Hello world":

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

**Coded template:** For example, let's say I have a coded template like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{{ content.html_title }}</title>
    {{ standard_header_includes }}
</head>
<body>
    <!-- I want to add custom module here, but how? -->
    {{ standard_footer_includes }}
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to add this custom module to a coded template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom modules can be embed using HubL statements.

For example, to display custom module with the title "Hello World" you can use such code:

```
<body>
    <!-- Custom module -->
    {% custom_widget "any_unique_id" widget_name='Hello World' %}

    {{ standard_footer_includes }}
</body>
```

Check HubL Reference for more information - https://designers.hubspot.com/docs/hubl/hubl-supported-modules